# What could be wrong with the LOGIN authorization in SMTP?

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, smtp, asyncore

So I'm working on own small SMTP server based on [SMTPD python module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html) source. Messages are received from IP cameras. When I try to get username connection stuck. Here is the log from my server. `<--` == Server, `-->` == Client

```
[2015-02-13 10:55:53] INFO: Server started at 192.168.0.103:1027
[2015-02-13 10:56:00] INFO: Incoming connection from ('**.***.****.****', 47178)
[2015-02-13 10:56:00] DEBUG: <-- '220 ****** SMTP Server 0.1 ESMTP'
[2015-02-13 10:56:00] DEBUG: --> EHLO : 'localhost' # ECHLO localhost
[2015-02-13 10:56:00] DEBUG: <-- '250-****** SMTP Server 0.1 Hello localhost'
[2015-02-13 10:56:00] DEBUG: <-- '250-SIZE 20480000'
[2015-02-13 10:56:00] DEBUG: <-- '250 AUTH PLAIN'
[2015-02-13 10:56:00] DEBUG: --> AUTH : 'LOGIN' # AUTH LOGIN
[2015-02-13 10:56:00] DEBUG: <-- '334 VXNlcm5hbWU6'
```

So as you can see after the Client selects `AUTH LOGIN`, then I request username like `334 VXNlcm5hbWU6` and here it stuck... The main thing is that with most of the cameras it works fine except few ones... But the most interesting thing is that when I test it with `nc` it works fine:

```
admin@X501A1 /var/www/html/py_email $ nc -v -l -p 1027
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 1027)
Connection from [**.***.****.****] port 1027 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 11726)
220 ***** SMTP Server 0.1
EHLO localhost
250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 # Here my server stucks
YWRtaW4=
# Further all works fine
```

I thing may be something is in terminator... Via `set_terminator` method I already tried `\n` and `\r\n`. Auth method looks like this:

```
def AUTH(self, arg):
    logging.debug('--> AUTH : ' + repr(arg))

    if 'PLAIN' in arg:
        pass
    elif 'LOGIN' in arg:
        split_args = arg.split(' ')

        if len(split_args) == 2:
            self._username = base64.b64decode(split_args[1])

            self.push('334 ' + str(base64.b64encode('Password:')))
        else:
            self.push('334 ' + str(base64.b64encode('Username:')))
    elif not self._username:
        self._username = base64.b64decode(arg)

        self.push('334 ' + base64.b64encode('Password:'))
```

Comment: Add some `try` block to further capture exceptions.